# folder icon and data are just loading not showing in php

Tags: php, mysql, treeview, syntax-error

I am new to PHP and I want to create a tree view with my MySQL DB in my PHP project I found a demo on this website

https://makitweb.com/demos/create-treeview-with-jstree-plugin-and-php

and I download this project and change the DB and table and columns name but after refreshing the page tree view just loading not showing anything please see the screenshot below link

[image: myiange]

please help me why this is happening and how it will resolve I am new in PHP i will be really thankful to you all guys.

Thanks

Comment: without seeing what you changed it  impossible to help you

Comment: i have just changed config file for db and user and index.php for table name and fields name thats it

Comment: i am not able to share my code here because of stack overflow don't allow me to paste here

Comment: look at the index file table name and column names are part of the programming, don't change anything besides the config file and then go from there

Comment: https://pastebin.com/u9YGJwL0

Comment: please see my code in that link

Comment: and the sub folders am jquery.min.js are also in the right place exacly like the original

Comment: yes everything as it is

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/sQjg8Ee.png

https://i.imgur.com/A1KO7VR.png

see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230684/discussion-between-muhammad-sajid-lakha-and-nbk).

Comment: no i mean like here https://imgur.com/a/STMtQi0

Comment: am not using this DB  i am using my DB

Comment: i think when you call the index.php it expects all files in that structure folder files and qall, ok the sql file you don't need but everything else like the jstree have to be exactly teh same

Comment: yes everything is exactly same in same manner i i didn't edit that files

Comment: can you please run this code on your computer

Comment: bro help me how it will resolve